# Eliminar espacio en blanco que genera una imagen al alterar su tamaño

Tags: html, css

Tengo problemas al crear un carrousel: al alterarse el tamaño de la imagen me genera un espacio en blanco que no consigo eliminar, lo que me genera un mayor ancho de la pestaña, y al abrir la herramienta de inspeccionar se ve aún más estirado generando que en el navbar sus botones no se logren visualizar. Los botones no tienen que ver nada, es una prueba para ver si me funciona el movimiento.

Cambie mis imagenes por algunas de internet para que se pueda visualizar correctamente el problema del fondo blanco que se genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
}
header ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin-left: 52em;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
header ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
header.abajo {
    background: black;
    transition: 1s;
}
.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.logo img {
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 40px;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: gray;
}

header.abajo .logo .img {
    height: 35px;
}

/* CARROUSEL*/

.carrousel {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 650px;
    top: -45px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imagenes {
    justify-items: center;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: tranform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.carrousel .imagenes .imgcollec {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1550px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.bottoms {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    top: -550px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="IMG\Daily Dose logo transparente blanco.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" class="nav-link">MÚSICA</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="nav-link">MODA</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="nav-link">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <body>
        <main class="carrousel">
            <article class="imagenes">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605810257524-b66f77c5066d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="1" class="imgcollec" />
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="2" class="imgcollec" />
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591213595166-82c13a93b1c8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80" alt="3" class="imgcollec" />
            </article>

            <nav class="bottoms">
                <button class="prev">Previus</button>
                <button class="next">Next</button>
            </nav>
        </main>
```

Comment: Para que efectivamente sea un [repro], reemplaza las rutas de las imágenes por URLs de sitios como _unsplash_, por dar un ejemplo.

Comment: Hice lo que me sugeriste y de igual manera esta el mismo problema del espacio blanco que sobra.

Comment: Claro, pero me refería a editar la pregunta para mostrar otras imágenes, para que logre verse el carrusel :) Actualmente solo se ven números con fondo blanco.

Comment: Listo ya lo arregle, no lo comprendí rápido.